# Weird issue with copypasta rust crate whilst setting clipboard context ( .set_contents )

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rust, clipboard, rust-cargo

I'm using the [copypasta](https://crates.io/crates/copypasta) rust crate which is fork from the [rust-clipboard](https://github.com/aweinstock314/rust-clipboard) library for reading and writing into my clipboard. **(I'm on Ubuntu 22 using the X11 clipboard, but this library supposedly supports windows and mac aswell)**

I also have the [xorg & x11](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/xorg) packages installed on my machine.

Getting the clipboard contents works as expected:

```rust
let mut ctx = ClipboardContext::new().unwrap();
println!("{:?}", ctx.get_contents());
```

Output of the print:

```
Ok("copied content")
```

This works fine

##### The issue / weird problem

When I try to set the clipboard content using the example directly from the docs

```rust
    let mut ctx: ClipboardContext = ClipboardProvider::new().unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", ctx.get_contents());
    ctx.set_contents("some string".to_owned()).unwrap();
```

Output of the print:

```
Ok("copied content")
```

Here it get's the content of the clip correctly, but instead of setting the clipboard to the new string, it simply deletes the currently set content and empties the clipboard.

**I've found a solution to this already;** After setting the clipboard contents you must call the get_contents function again, then it works, but it's just weird that I need to do this..

```rust
    let mut ctx = ClipboardContext::new().unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", ctx.get_contents());
    ctx.set_contents("s0m3 str1ng".to_string()).unwrap();
    ctx.get_contents();
```

This block of code works and successfully set's the clipboard to: `s0m3 str1ng`

If you've got some experience with rust-clipboard or the copypasta fork, has this ever happened to you? People using this crate on other operation systems, does this bug occur? Why is the calling of get_contents again necessary?

Comment: Works for me, on Win11. If that really is the behavior you observe, then this looks like it is a bug in copypasta. Although I'd be very confused if nobody encountered this earlier.

Comment: I can confirm it's broken on x11, Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Cool, thanks for confirming it on Windows, I guess it's just a linux thing  ...